# Deep filter value using functional programming principles

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

`deepFilter` function uses a `predicate` to filter properties which may be nested deeply in the given `value` (object or array). It returns filtered object or array.

The code works for most inputs (arbitrary levels of nesting and input without cyclic references). I'm more interested in comments on my approach to FP than correctness of the code. Though I wouldn't mind if you point a mistake.

```
const and = (f1, f2) => v => f1(v) && f2(v);

const or = (f1, f2) => v => f1(v) || f2(v);

const isArray = v => Array.isArray(v);

const isObject = v => typeof v === 'object' && v !== null;

const hasProps = v => Object.keys(v).length > 0;

const selector = (predicate, v1, v2) => v => (predicate(v) ? v1 : v2);

const isObjectOrArray = or(isArray, isObject);

const hasValue = and(isObjectOrArray, hasProps);

const initial = selector(isArray, [], {});

function deepFilter(value, predicate) {
  if (isObjectOrArray(value)) {
    return Object.keys(value).reduce((filtered, key) => {
      if (predicate(key)) {
        return { ...filtered, [key]: value[key] };
      }
      const v = deepFilter(value[key], predicate);
      return hasValue(v) ? { ...filtered, [key]: v } : filtered;
    }, initial(value));
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Problem with your code is that many JavaScript objects are cyclic, and you do not check. eg Try and run `deepFilter(window, v => v === "somePropertyName");`

Comment: Good catch. I need to see how I can work around those situations. Thanks.